# Program to print and sum numbers in a text file

Tags: c

I want to write a program which print all numbers found in a file and then add them up. I have two problems:

1. How to add up the numbers I've printed?
2. Why in output_file do I have so many commas:
   [image: Superfluous Commas]

**Here's my code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define CHUNK 12

char *getWord(FILE *infile);
void clean(char *dirty);

char *getWord(FILE *infile)
{
    char *word, *word2;
    int length, cursor, c;

    word = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*CHUNK);
    if(word == NULL) return NULL;

    length = CHUNK;
    cursor = 0;

    while(!isspace(c = getc(infile)) && !feof(infile))
    {
        word[cursor] = c;
        cursor++;

        if(cursor >= length)
        {
            length += CHUNK;

            word2 = (char*)realloc(word, cursor);
            if(word2 == NULL)
            {
                free(word2);
                return NULL;
            }
            else 
            {
                word = word2;
            }
        }
    }

    word[cursor] = '\0';
    return word;
}

void clean(char *dirty)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0; 
    char *temp;

    temp = strdup(dirty);
    while(i < strlen(temp))
    {
        if(isdigit(temp[i]))
        {
            dirty[j] = temp[i];
            j++;
        }

        i++;
    }

    dirty[j] = '\0';
    free(temp);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    char *word;
    FILE *infile, *outfile;

    if(argc != 3)
    {
        printf("Missing argument!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    infile = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if(infile != NULL)
    {

        outfile = fopen(argv[2], "w");
        if(outfile == NULL)
        {
            printf("Error, cannot open the outfile!\n");
            abort();
        }
        else 
        {
            while(!feof(infile))
            {
                word = getWord(infile);
                if(word == NULL)
                {
                    free(word);
                    abort();
                }

                clean(word);

                fputs(word, outfile);
                fputs(",", outfile);
                free(word);
            }
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        printf("Error, cannot open the outfile!\n");
        abort();
    }

    fclose(infile);
    fclose(outfile);
    return 0;
}
```

infile:
[image]

Comment: If you want to show output, please paste it as text; don't include a screenshot image unless it's necessary (which it isn't here).

Comment: are you aware of the `+` operator? That's what you use to add numbers...

Comment: you could also upload the file you are taking the numbers from

Comment: You are reading numbers, but storing them as strings. Of course it's hard to add them up. Try using `fscanf` with `"%d"`.

Comment: We don't know what input files you're reading or what's in them. Presumably you can exhibit the same problem by narrowing your program down to a smaller one that doesn't depend on the contents of input files. http://sscce.org/

Comment: `feof()` is not the right way to detect an end-of-file condition. Check the value returned by your input function, in this case `getc(infile)`, which returns the special value `EOF` on end-of-file or error. The `feof()` function should be used only to distinguish between end-of-file and an error condition *after* you've detected that there's no more input.

Comment: An example of your input file would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting `,` because of this -

```
fputs(",", outfile);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is related in structure to the `echo` unix command. The core of the program could be simplified to something along the following lines:

```
  int c, need_comma = 0;

  while ((c = fgetc(infile)) != EOF) {
    if (isdigit(c)) {
      fputc(c, outfile);
      need_comma = 1;
    }
    else {
      if (need_comma == 1) {
        fputc(',', outfile);
        need_comma = 0;
      }
    }
  }
```

this removes the need for `getWord` and `clean` functions.

This is just the printing part. the intermediate file is in CSV format,
which is structured and easy to parse and add the numbers (and print the
result to another file).