# How to remove leading zeros from output_file?

Tags: c

I have problem with getNumber function, because my output_file contains zeros. And in my opinion it should not. I want my program to print all numbers and then add them up.

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define CHUNK 12

char *getNumber(FILE *infile);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *number, *pEnd;
    FILE *infile, *outfile;
    int newNumber, sum = 0;

    if(argc != 3)
    {
        printf("Missing argument!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    infile = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if(infile != NULL)
    {
        outfile = fopen(argv[2], "w");
        if(outfile == NULL)
        {
            printf("Error, cannot open the outfile!\n");
            abort();
        }
        else
        {
            while(!feof(infile))
            {
                number = getNumber(infile);

                if(number == NULL)
                {
                    free(number);
                    abort();
                }
                newNumber = strtol(number, &pEnd, 10);
                sum += newNumber;

                 if(!*pEnd)
                    printf("Converted successfully!\n");
                    else printf("Conversion error, non-convertible part: %s", pEnd);

                fprintf(outfile, "%d\n", newNumber);
                free(number);
            }
            fprintf(outfile, "\nSum: %d\n", sum);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Error, cannot open the infile!\n");
        abort();
    }

    fclose(infile);
    fclose(outfile);
    return 0;
}   

char *getNumber(FILE *infile)
{
    char *number, *number2;
    int length, cursor = 0, c;dwwd

    number = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*CHUNK);
    if(number == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error!\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    length = CHUNK;

    while(!isspace(c = getc(infile)) && !feof(infile))
    {
        if(isdigit(c))
        {
            number[cursor] = c;
            cursor++;

            if(cursor >= length)
            {
                length += CHUNK;
                number2 = (char*)realloc(number, cursor);
                if(number2 == NULL)
                {
                    free(number);
                    return NULL;
                }
                else number = number2;
            }
        }
    }
    number[cursor] = '\0';
    return number;
}
```

I would be really grateful for any help.

I am also sending two files, input_file and output_file:
[image: input_file]
[image: output_file]

Comment: It would help if you briefly stated what you wanted to accomplish with your program, so we don't have to guess from reading your code.

Comment: I want my program to print all numbers and then add them up.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [the OPs previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18552783/program-to-print-and-sum-numbers-in-a-text-file). Also, you were asked *not* to include screenshots for trivial text output.

Comment: I add screenshots because people do not understand correctly the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add else statement to your if(isdigit(c)) to break the loop when a non digit character is found after having found a digit previously.

```
if(isdigit(c))
{
    // your existing code
}
else if (cursor != 0)
{
    break;
}
```

Hope this helps.

**EDIT:**

Just replace

```
fprintf(outfile, "%d\n", newNumber);
```

with

```
if(0 != newNumber) fprintf(outfile, "%d\n", newNumber);
```

Comment: unfortunately, still the same.

Comment: This (edited) solution may work, but it is fixing the symptoms instead of fixing the actual problem with getNumber. From the way the code is written, getNumber is supposed to yield a number every time it is called, not return virtual zeroes. This solution also doesn't account for the case where there *is* a 0 in the input, which might have to be output to the file.

Comment: @JeSuisse: Your are right. There is a problem with the logic that each invocation of getNumber() is expected to return a number. Which is a wrong assumption. And the case of non existing number is not handled. I will leave that to all0Star. The logic to handle is to check the length of number string before converting it to long.

Answer (score 1):

Your condition here:

```
while(!isspace(c = getc(infile)) && !feof(infile))
```

Breaks every time you encounter space. After that you will always print the number. That means that for every interval(also for the end of the file) that is not preceded directly with digit you will print one extra zero in the output file.

Maybe add one flag whether you entered the while at least once. If you have not - just do not print anything.

Answer (score 0):

From the strtol c library manpage:

> If there were no digits at all, strtol()  stores
>          the  original value of nptr in *endptr (and returns 0)

You always assign to newNumber and don't check for the case where strtol doesn't actually return a converted number but a instead returns a 0 because it couldn't find a number. That's why you have all the zeroes in your output file.

Comment: I still think it is rather connected to spaces. You can also verify it with the given example - a zero is printed per each interval that is not preceded with word containing digit

Comment: Hmmm, yes, I guess you analyzed one more step than me. I stopped when I noticed that getNumber may return non-numbers (empty strings), which strtol converts to 0s, and you found the reason why getNumber doesn't return a string of actual numbers.